# Save UTF8 string to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, utf-8

I have a string in UTF8 like:

```
Thermal Oxide: 0 Å to 40 μm
```

and I want to save it in SQL Server.

When I save it in data type ntext/nvarchar - it saves like this:

```
Thermal Oxide: 0 ? to 40 ?m
```

What can I do?

Comment: It all depends on how you (un)save it.

Comment: **HOW** are you saving it?? `Nvarchar` is **definitely** able to store this string - no problem at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Precede the quoted string with `N`:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (myField) VALUES (N'Thermal Oxide: 0 Å to 40 μm')
```

Comment: Why the sudden downvote? If I could improve the answer I would love to know how.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a string in UTF8 like:

Actually, no you don't - you have a unicode string. UTF8, however, only applies to how it is encoded, i.e. storage. If you mean you want to store it, fine; simply: make sure the column you store it in is `nvarchar(somelen)` (or similar), and that you use parameters to store it. If you just use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paramName", yourString);` that'll be fine (for TSQL like `insert [tablename] (...fields...) values (..., @foo)` etc). Likewise, any ORM / micro-ORM / other database tool will work fine with this, as long as the column is `nvarchar(somelen)` or similar. For example, with "dapper":

```
string s = "Thermal Oxide: 0 Å to 40 μm";
connection.Execute("insert [tablename] (colname) values (@s)", new {s});
```

Comment: Hi Marc! Why `new {s}` as opposed to simply `s`? Also, the string `s` has a preceding single-quote but no close single-quote.

Comment: @dotancohen the single quote shouldn't have been there, sorry. Re "simply `s`" - dapper uses that as the parameter name; `new {s}` represents an anonymous type with a string member `s` with value `"Thermal ..."` - everything we need to run it as a parameterised command